# Show $F_M(t) = P(M \leq t) = t^n$ where $M$ is the $\max$ of $n$ uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was given the following problem for homework, and I am having trouble understanding the Max part of the question.  I know the use of integrals is needed but I am not familiar with integrating a max function.  any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent random variables,
each having uniform distribution over $(0, 1)$. Let
$$M = \max(X_1, X_2, \dotsc , X_n).$$
Show that the distribution function of $M$ is
$$F_M(t) = P(M \leq t) = t^n$$
for $t \in (0, 1)$.

What is the density function of $M$?

Comment: Seems straight forward.  What trouble are you having with this?

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have to integrate the max function but I am not sure how to do this.  I can do these fine when I have a function i know. Polynomial for example.

Comment: have you recognize the crucial relationship: $\max\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \leq t \iff x_1 \leq t \text{ and } x_2 \leq t \text{ and } \ldots \text{ and } x_n \leq t$

Comment: Also, you do not have to *integrate* anything.  The *probability density function* (of a continuous random variable) is the *derivative* of the *cumulative distribution function*.

Comment: makes sense @jim?

Answer (score 0):

The cdf of each $X_i\sim U(0,1)$ is $$F_{X_i}(t)=\Pr(X_i\le t)=t,\, t\in[0,1]$$ 
When the maximum of random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is less than $t$, it means all of them are less than $t$. That is :
$$F_M(t)=\Pr(M\le t)=\Pr(X_1\le t, X_2\le t,\cdots,X_3\le t)$$
Since $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$  are independent, the above joint probability is the product of marginal probabilities:
$$\Pr(X_1\le t, X_2\le t,\cdots,X_3\le t)=\Pr(X_1\le t)\Pr(X_2\le t)\cdots \Pr(X_n\le t)=t^n$$

Differentiate $F_M(t)$ to get the pdf.